# How to add same Ubuntu operating system as backup to GRUB?

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, grub

I have 4 partitions on my hard disk:

- 15 GB Ubuntu OS (mounted to /) - sda 2
- 15 GB Backup (not mounted) - sda 3
- 505 MB Grub (/boot/efi) - sda 1
- 89 GB GB Data (mount /data) - sda 4

For LTS updates, e.g. 16.04 to 18.04, I want to copy (with dd) my first partition (`sda2`) to the second (`sda3`).
That way, I can do the release update on `sda2` and if this fails, I have a backup on `sda3`.

I tried a lot of stuff to boot from `sda3`, but the menu entry doesn't show 
 up (I used `update-grub`).

Used dd command: `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sda3`

My file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Backup" {
set root=(hd0,3)
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3 ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
}
```

Output of `update-grub`

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

My File `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

```
default         0
timeout         0
hiddenmenu

title           Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, kernel 4.15.0-47-generic
root            (hd0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-47-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro console=hvc0
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic

title           Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, kernel 4.15.0-47-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-47-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
```

Comment: @terdon i added now a custom menuentry.. see above...

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer now! Did you run `grub-install` after `update-grub`? If not, no new menu entry will be created if I remember correctly.

Comment: In the example above i only run grub-install, the menuentry is shown in grub. But it boots the same system as the original boot entry (both sda2)

Comment: What? Why didn't you mention that then? What menu entry? Please tell us all of these details, it is really tiring to have to drag them out of you bit by bit like this. The more information you give us, the better our chances of understanding and helping you.

Comment: I installed a fresh ubuntu, added the menuentry in the 40_custom file, did a `update-grub`.
The menuentry is shown on grub but both entries (the original and the new custom) boot from sda2.

Comment: Please check in `/etc/default/grub` if there is a line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` and change this value to `false`. I guess with the new setting your backup partition should be found and create a new menu entry when you run `update-grub` again.

Comment: Look, please make _edits_ to your question to add new information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. You say you added a menu entry, but your grub file only shows the 2 normal ones. So which one did you add? You say you tried it but it booted the normal OS, again, which one did you try? Your `update-grub` output shows that the 40_custom file was not read, so either you ran it before creating the file or there is something else wrong.

Comment: @Freddy 
There is no Variable `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER`, i added it with `false` as value but it still boots from sda2     
   
@terdon
I never said there are two normals...
The 40_custom file must be readed because i see the normale entry (created while ubuntu setup) and my new entry(called Backup), but both boots from sda2

Comment: I found out that if i select my custom entry(called backup) and press e there is the sda2 is linked..

I can change anything in the 40_custom file and use `update-grub` but will change there.

Comment: You say you see the "backup" entry. Where do you see it? How can we know this? It isn't in any of the files you actually show in your question.

Comment: Might be that grub has a problem with the backup partition, because it has the same UUID. Check with `ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid` first, then change the UUID of your backup partition with `tune2fs -U random /dev/sda3`, then run `ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid` again to get the new value, mount your backup partition and update the old UUID in `/path/to/mounted-backup-partition/etc/fstab`, then `umount /dev/sda3` and run `update-grub` again.

Comment: @Freddy Thank you this fixed the issue... both had the same uuid...